# Is it a good style to use this to refer private member in the class?

Tags: c++

I have a class like

```
class T {
private:
    int x;

public:
    int getX() {
       return this->x;
    }
}
```

Is it good to use `this->x` rather than `x` itself?

Comment: It would be better to learn basic C++ syntax before obsessing over subjective trivialities such as this.

Comment: Simply do it like you want, but always in the same way in the whole software! Use Coding Standards for your project. I dislike this->x for every local var, but I also hate m_bla for ever variable. If my methods and classes so big and the parameter lists for a method is so long that I can't see which is a parameter, a local var and a class member, I should rethink of the design and interfaces. But better to have m_bla in big interfaces instead have nothing.

Comment: No. It is not good to use this->x than x. Because it doesn't create much of difference. Rather than you have to type a bunch of characters more. It is only helpful in the case of having global and local variable of same name

Comment: "good style" is a matter of opinion, and therefore off-topic.  You *could* [edit] this question to ask something non-subjective, such as "When **must** one form be used over the other?"

Answer (score -1):

No. Perhaps use `m_x` instead. It signify that it is a member variable.

Perhaps read about the use of `const`

Comment: what if i have a variable m_x

Comment: which one is antipattern, this->x, m_x, or _x?

Comment: @AdamLee - When I see `_x` I think "something implementation specific in the global namespace", like `_getch()`.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it makes clear that you mean a member variable here, not a parameter, local variable, etc.

Comment: No, it makes me wonder why you specifically **have to** use `this->x` here. Are there other things named `x` around, or is `x` a member of a templated base class? No?